# How to change entire row if NaN present if a single column has NaN

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I have a DataFrame like this

```
                    gauge       satellite
1979-06-23 18:00:00 6.700000    2.484378
1979-06-27 03:00:00 NaN         8.891460
1979-06-27 06:00:00 1.833333    4.053460
1979-06-27 09:00:00 NaN         2.876649
1979-07-31 18:00:00 6.066667    1.438324
```

I want to obtain a DataFrame Like this

```
                    gauge       satellite
1979-06-23 18:00:00 6.700000    2.484378
1979-06-27 03:00:00 NaN         NaN
1979-06-27 06:00:00 1.833333    4.053460
1979-06-27 09:00:00 NaN         NaN
1979-07-31 18:00:00 6.066667    1.438324
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What I will do `reindex`

```
df.dropna().reindex(df.index)
```

Comment: Woooo... now, that is creative. +1

Comment: @modyrockett yw :-) happy coding

Answer (score 3):

`mask`:

```
df.mask(df.gauge.isna())
```

---

```
                        gauge  satellite
1979-06-23 18:00:00  6.700000   2.484378
1979-06-27 03:00:00       NaN        NaN
1979-06-27 06:00:00  1.833333   4.053460
1979-06-27 09:00:00       NaN        NaN
1979-07-31 18:00:00  6.066667   1.438324
```

Answer (score 2):

use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to add nan

```
import numpy as np
df['satellite'] = np.where(df['gauge'].isnull(),np.nan,df['satellite'])
```

## Second solution

use `.loc` and `isnull`

```
df.loc[df['guage'].isnull(),'satellite'] = np.nan
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `np.where`:

```
df['satellite'] = np.where(df['gauge'].isna(), np.NaN, df['satellite'])
df['gauge'] = np.where(df['satellite'].isna(), np.NaN, df['gauge'])
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to find if a row has `np.nan`. [`.any(1)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) gives you masking for a row.

```
df.loc[df.isna().any(1)] = np.nan
```

Output:

```
                        gauge       satellite
1979-06-23  18:00:00    6.700000    2.484378
1979-06-27  03:00:00    NaN         NaN
1979-06-27  06:00:00    1.833333    4.053460
1979-06-27  09:00:00    NaN         NaN
1979-07-31  18:00:00    6.066667    1.438324
```